# rsync creates directories that are excluded

Tags: rsync

I'm confused about how rsync includes/excludes files and directories. I have an exclude file:

```
/home/pi/rsync-exclude.txt
```

with contents:

```
/proc/*
/sys/*
/dev/*
/boot/*
/tmp/*
/run/*
/mnt/*
/media/*

.Trashes
._.Trashes
.fseventsd
.Spotlight-V100
.DS_Store
.AppleDesktop
.AppleDB
Network Trash Folder
Temporary Items

.bash_history
/etc/fake-hwclock.data
/var/lib/rpimonitor/stat/
```

and I'm using the following syntax for rsync:

```
sudo rsync -avH --delete-during --delete-excluded --exclude-from=/home/pi/rsync-exclude.txt / /mnt/
```

but rsync is creating the directories /mnt/proc, /mnt/sys, etc. They're empty as they should be but I'd prefer if they weren't there at all.

Is there a different syntax I can use to cause rsync to ignore the directories entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expressions exclude the contents of the directories (`/foo/*`), not the directories themselves (`/proc`). For example:

```
$ mkdir -p foo/{1..3}/{1..3}
$ cat exclude.txt 
/1/*
/2
$ rsync -avH --exclude-from=exclude.txt foo/ bar
sending incremental file list
created directory bar
./
1/
3/
3/1/
3/2/
3/3/

sent 296 bytes  received 89 bytes  770.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

As can be seen, simply using the directory path is enough to exclude it and all its contents. Oddly enough, you have used this at the end of your exclude list:

> ```
> /var/lib/rpimonitor/stat/
> ```